# Convert Data Frame to time Series

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series

```
Year    Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
2015    75  74  60  57  67  131 299 138 329 333 307 213
2016    141 174 72  219 139 163 160 82  150 177 138 138
```

Above is data that I am working on. I have imported data to R, Initially this is getting imported as `data.frame`.

Importing the data from `xlsx` file using `xlsx` library

```
class(test)
"data.frame"
```

I want the class to be converted to `ts`. I have tried few of the existing method but I am still not able get it done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this seems to work:

```
ts(df[-1], frequency = 1, start = df[1, 1], end = df[2, 1])
```

Output:

```
Time Series:
Start = 2015 
End = 2016 
Frequency = 1 
     Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
2015  75  74  60  57  67 131 299 138 329 333 307 213
2016 141 174  72 219 139 163 160  82 150 177 138 138
```

Comment: thanks for the update. This method works perfectly fine

Comment: You are very welcome @PraveenRKaruppannan. Happy to help :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
test = ts(unlist(df[,-1]), start = df[1,1], frequency = ncol(df[,-1]))

test
#     Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
#2015  75 141  74 174  60  72  57 219  67 139 131 163
#2016 299 160 138  82 329 150 333 177 307 138 213 138

class(test)
#[1] "ts"

#Obtain the frequency
unique(cycle(test))
#[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12

#Obtain the years
unique(floor(time(test)))
#[1] 2015 2016
```